# JqueryUI Explode - where is color coming from?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm working on an animation and I want to have a a balloon pop at a certain point. I discovered Explode in the jQueryUi and thought I would give it a go. I have it exploding but the pieces don't seem to have a color. I can't find where they should be getting their color from. In the examples the color seems to be the same as the element but that isn't happening for me. Is that because it is an element in a SVG?

Examples I referred to:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jquery/effect-explode.htm

https://api.jqueryui.com/explode-effect/

You can see it happening at about 20 seconds on the balloon carrying the turtle when it stops.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $( "#ballon" ).delay(20000).toggle( "explode" );
}); //end document.ready
```

```css
html {
 box-sizing:border-box;
}
*,
*:before,
*:after { /* allow all elements to inherit box-sizing */
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
html, body { 
 margin:0; 
 padding:0; 
 overflow:hidden; 
 width: 100vw;
 height: 100vh;
}


.BalloonContainer {
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

.flying img {
 max-width: 150px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 20px;
 transform: translateX(-30vw);
 animation: moveBird 2s linear 22s 1 forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes moveBird {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-30vw) rotate(3deg);
    
  }
  50% {
 transform: rotate(-3deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(45vw) rotate(3deg);
    
  }
}

.initialBalloon {
  position: absolute;
  /* moves initial position before animating */
  transform: translateX(100vw);
  top: 150px;
  animation: moveFirst 2s linear .2s 1;
  
  width: 150px;
}

.firstBalloon {
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateX(-30vw);
  top: 150px;
  animation: move 5s linear 5s infinite;
  width: 150px;
}

.secondBalloon {
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateX(-30vw);
  top: 200px;
  animation: move 8s linear 0s infinite;
  width: 150px;
}

.thirdBalloon {
  top: 250px;
  transform: translateX(-30vw);
  position: absolute;
  animation: move 11s linear 1s infinite;
  width: 150px;
}
.turtle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  transform: translateX(-50vw); 
  
  animation: moveTurtle 5s linear 1s 1 none, 
  moveTurtleStop 11s linear 6s 1 forwards, 
  moveTurtleRotate 5s linear 17s infinite;  
  width: 250px;
}



@-webkit-keyframes moveTurtle {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-50vw) rotate(10deg);
    
  }
  50% {
 transform: rotate(-5deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(100vw) rotate(10deg);
    
  }
}

 @-webkit-keyframes moveTurtleRotate {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(50vw) rotate(10deg);    
  }
  50% {
 transform: translateX(50vw) rotate(-5deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(50vw) rotate(10deg);    
  }
} 

@-webkit-keyframes moveTurtleStop {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-50vw) rotate(10deg);
    
  }
  50% {
 transform: rotate(-5deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(50vw) rotate(10deg);
    
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes move {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-30vw) rotate(10deg);
    
  }
  50% {
 transform: rotate(-5deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(100vw) rotate(10deg);
    
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes moveFirst {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(50vw) rotate(10deg);
  }
  50% {
 transform: translateX(75vw) transform: rotate(-5deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(100vw) rotate(10deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="BalloonContainer">
  <div class="flying">
   <img src="https://williamcunningham.me/happy_birthday_2019/img/flyNew.gif" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="initialBalloon swingimage">
   <svg id="Balloon_1" data-name="Balloon_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 48.82 125.26"><defs><style>.cls-1 {fill: #171618;}.cls-2 {fill: #efefef;}</style></defs><title>ballon</title><path id="ballon_1p" class="cls-1" d="M15.34,1.26s-18,9-15,26,19,28,19,28a22.69,22.69,0,0,0,4,1c1,0-2,2-1,3h5s2,0-1-3c0,0,18-6,22-28S30.34-3.74,15.34,1.26Z" /><path id="highlight_1" class="cls-2" d="M18.34,6.26s-15,6-13,20h6S8.34,14.26,18.34,6.26Z" />
       <polygon id="string_1" class="cls-1" points="22.34 125.26 24.41 57.26 25.57 57.26 26.34 125.26 22.34 125.26" /></svg>
  </div>
  <div class="firstBalloon swingimage">
   <svg id="Balloon_2" data-name="Balloon_2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 48.82 125.26"><defs><style>.cls-1 {fill: #171618;}.cls-2 {fill: #efefef;}</style></defs><title>ballon</title><path id="ballon_2p" class="cls-1" d="M15.34,1.26s-18,9-15,26,19,28,19,28a22.69,22.69,0,0,0,4,1c1,0-2,2-1,3h5s2,0-1-3c0,0,18-6,22-28S30.34-3.74,15.34,1.26Z" /><path id="highlight_2" class="cls-2" d="M18.34,6.26s-15,6-13,20h6S8.34,14.26,18.34,6.26Z" />
       <polygon id="string_2" class="cls-1" points="22.34 125.26 24.41 57.26 25.57 57.26 26.34 125.26 22.34 125.26" /></svg>
  </div>
  <div class="secondBalloon swingimage">
   <svg id="Balloon_3" data-name="Balloon_3" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 48.82 125.26"><defs><style>.cls-1 {fill: #171618;}.cls-2 {fill: #efefef;}</style></defs><title>ballon</title><path id="ballon_3p" class="cls-1" d="M15.34,1.26s-18,9-15,26,19,28,19,28a22.69,22.69,0,0,0,4,1c1,0-2,2-1,3h5s2,0-1-3c0,0,18-6,22-28S30.34-3.74,15.34,1.26Z" /><path id="highlight_3" class="cls-2" d="M18.34,6.26s-15,6-13,20h6S8.34,14.26,18.34,6.26Z" />
       <polygon id="string_3" class="cls-1" points="22.34 125.26 24.41 57.26 25.57 57.26 26.34 125.26 22.34 125.26" /></svg>
  </div>
  <div class="thirdBalloon swingimage">
   <svg id="Balloon_4" data-name="Balloon_4" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 48.82 125.26"><defs><style>.cls-1 {fill: #171618;}.cls-2 {fill: #efefef;}</style></defs><title>ballon</title><path id="ballon_4p" class="cls-1" d="M15.34,1.26s-18,9-15,26,19,28,19,28a22.69,22.69,0,0,0,4,1c1,0-2,2-1,3h5s2,0-1-3c0,0,18-6,22-28S30.34-3.74,15.34,1.26Z" /><path id="highlight_4" class="cls-2" d="M18.34,6.26s-15,6-13,20h6S8.34,14.26,18.34,6.26Z" />
       <polygon id="string_4" class="cls-1" points="22.34 125.26 24.41 57.26 25.57 57.26 26.34 125.26 22.34 125.26" /></svg>
  </div>
  <div class="turtle swingimage">
   <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 110.09 179.26"><defs><style>.cls-1{fill:#171618;}.cls-2{fill:#efefef;}</style></defs><title>fullTurtle</title><g id="balloonTotal"><path id="ballon" class="cls-1" d="M34.13,1.26s-18,9-15,26,19,28,19,28a22.69,22.69,0,0,0,4,1c1,0-2,2-1,3h5s2,0-1-3c0,0,18-6,22-28S49.13-3.74,34.13,1.26Z"/><path id="highlight" class="cls-2" d="M37.13,6.26s-15,6-13,20h6S27.13,14.26,37.13,6.26Z"/><polygon id="string" class="cls-1" points="41.13 125.26 43.2 57.26 44.37 57.26 45.13 125.26 41.13 125.26"/></g><g id="turtle"><path id="body" class="cls-1" d="M37.13,122.26s-18-1-33,20c0,0-5,1-4,4s8,8,6,11-7,9-4,12,15-6,15-6,18,12,41,1c0,0,2,0,2,4s-1,11,2,11,10-12,10-12,4-4,1-7c0,0-2-2-1-3s7-6,11-1,4,7,10,7,14-3,14-3,5-2,2-6a39.88,39.88,0,0,0-7-7s-2-3-7-2-10,3-8,1,2-3-1-3c-1,0-18-16-29-18S45.13,122.26,37.13,122.26Z"/><path id="highlight-2" data-name="highlight" class="cls-2" d="M5.13,145.26s26,36,76,0C81.13,145.26,34.13,188.26,5.13,145.26Z"/><circle id="eye" class="cls-2" cx="97.63" cy="152.76" r="4.5"/><circle id="eyeball" class="cls-1" cx="99.13" cy="152.26" r="1"/></g></svg> 
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Could you provide a link to the examples you are mentioning?

Comment: @Peter, 
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jquery/effect-explode.htm

https://api.jqueryui.com/explode-effect/

Comment: When I run your code snipper, I get an error: `"message": "Script error.",
  "filename": "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"`

Comment: Must load jQuery before jQuery UI.

Comment: I also do not see where `#ballon` exists in your HTML.

Comment: @Twisty Thanks. Got this posted and had to run so couldn't get back to it until now.

Comment: @Twisty the #ballon is in .turtle, the last div. It is a path: <path id="ballon"

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that this is related to using an `<svg><path>` versus a `<div>` or `<img>` element.

If we break this down to a slimmer version we can see what is happens:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#ballon, #highlight").delay(30 * 1000).toggle("explode", {
    pieces: 16
  }, 500);

  $(".flying img").delay(32 * 1000).toggle("explode", {
    pieces: 42
  }, 2000);
});
```

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  /* allow all elements to inherit box-sizing */
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.BalloonContainer {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.flying img {
  max-width: 150px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  transform: translateX(-30vw);
  animation: moveBird 2s linear 22s 1 forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes moveBird {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-30vw) rotate(3deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(-3deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(45vw) rotate(3deg);
  }
}

.initialBalloon {
  position: absolute;
  /* moves initial position before animating */
  transform: translateX(100vw);
  top: 150px;
  animation: moveFirst 2s linear .2s 1;
  width: 150px;
}

.firstBalloon {
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateX(-30vw);
  top: 150px;
  animation: move 5s linear 5s infinite;
  width: 150px;
}

.secondBalloon {
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateX(-30vw);
  top: 200px;
  animation: move 8s linear 0s infinite;
  width: 150px;
}

.thirdBalloon {
  top: 250px;
  transform: translateX(-30vw);
  position: absolute;
  animation: move 11s linear 1s infinite;
  width: 150px;
}

.turtle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  transform: translateX(-50vw);
  animation: moveTurtle 5s linear 1s 1 none, moveTurtleStop 11s linear 6s 1 forwards, moveTurtleRotate 5s linear 17s infinite;
  width: 250px;
}

@-webkit-keyframes moveTurtle {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-50vw) rotate(10deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(-5deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(100vw) rotate(10deg);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes moveTurtleRotate {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(50vw) rotate(10deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateX(50vw) rotate(-5deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(50vw) rotate(10deg);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes moveTurtleStop {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-50vw) rotate(10deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(-5deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(50vw) rotate(10deg);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes move {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-30vw) rotate(10deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(-5deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(100vw) rotate(10deg);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes moveFirst {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(50vw) rotate(10deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateX(75vw) transform: rotate(-5deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(100vw) rotate(10deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class="BalloonContainer">
  <div class="flying">
    <img src="https://williamcunningham.me/happy_birthday_2019/img/flyNew.gif" alt="">
  </div>
  <!--
  <div class="initialBalloon swingimage">
    <svg id="Balloon_1" data-name="Balloon_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 48.82 125.26"><defs><style>.cls-1 {fill: #171618;}.cls-2 {fill: #efefef;}</style></defs><title>ballon</title><path id="ballon_1p" class="cls-1" d="M15.34,1.26s-18,9-15,26,19,28,19,28a22.69,22.69,0,0,0,4,1c1,0-2,2-1,3h5s2,0-1-3c0,0,18-6,22-28S30.34-3.74,15.34,1.26Z" /><path id="highlight_1" class="cls-2" d="M18.34,6.26s-15,6-13,20h6S8.34,14.26,18.34,6.26Z" />
       <polygon id="string_1" class="cls-1" points="22.34 125.26 24.41 57.26 25.57 57.26 26.34 125.26 22.34 125.26" /></svg>
  </div>
  <div class="firstBalloon swingimage">
    <svg id="Balloon_2" data-name="Balloon_2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 48.82 125.26"><defs><style>.cls-1 {fill: #171618;}.cls-2 {fill: #efefef;}</style></defs><title>ballon</title><path id="ballon_2p" class="cls-1" d="M15.34,1.26s-18,9-15,26,19,28,19,28a22.69,22.69,0,0,0,4,1c1,0-2,2-1,3h5s2,0-1-3c0,0,18-6,22-28S30.34-3.74,15.34,1.26Z" /><path id="highlight_2" class="cls-2" d="M18.34,6.26s-15,6-13,20h6S8.34,14.26,18.34,6.26Z" />
       <polygon id="string_2" class="cls-1" points="22.34 125.26 24.41 57.26 25.57 57.26 26.34 125.26 22.34 125.26" /></svg>
  </div>
  <div class="secondBalloon swingimage">
    <svg id="Balloon_3" data-name="Balloon_3" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 48.82 125.26"><defs><style>.cls-1 {fill: #171618;}.cls-2 {fill: #efefef;}</style></defs><title>ballon</title><path id="ballon_3p" class="cls-1" d="M15.34,1.26s-18,9-15,26,19,28,19,28a22.69,22.69,0,0,0,4,1c1,0-2,2-1,3h5s2,0-1-3c0,0,18-6,22-28S30.34-3.74,15.34,1.26Z" /><path id="highlight_3" class="cls-2" d="M18.34,6.26s-15,6-13,20h6S8.34,14.26,18.34,6.26Z" />
       <polygon id="string_3" class="cls-1" points="22.34 125.26 24.41 57.26 25.57 57.26 26.34 125.26 22.34 125.26" /></svg>
  </div>
  <div class="thirdBalloon swingimage">
    <svg id="Balloon_4" data-name="Balloon_4" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 48.82 125.26"><defs><style>.cls-1 {fill: #171618;}.cls-2 {fill: #efefef;}</style></defs><title>ballon</title><path id="ballon_4p" class="cls-1" d="M15.34,1.26s-18,9-15,26,19,28,19,28a22.69,22.69,0,0,0,4,1c1,0-2,2-1,3h5s2,0-1-3c0,0,18-6,22-28S30.34-3.74,15.34,1.26Z" /><path id="highlight_4" class="cls-2" d="M18.34,6.26s-15,6-13,20h6S8.34,14.26,18.34,6.26Z" />
       <polygon id="string_4" class="cls-1" points="22.34 125.26 24.41 57.26 25.57 57.26 26.34 125.26 22.34 125.26" /></svg>
  </div>
  -->
  <div class="turtle swingimage">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 110.09 179.26"><defs><style>.cls-1{fill:#171618;}.cls-2{fill:#efefef;}</style></defs><title>fullTurtle</title><g id="balloonTotal"><path id="ballon" class="cls-1" d="M34.13,1.26s-18,9-15,26,19,28,19,28a22.69,22.69,0,0,0,4,1c1,0-2,2-1,3h5s2,0-1-3c0,0,18-6,22-28S49.13-3.74,34.13,1.26Z"/><path id="highlight" class="cls-2" d="M37.13,6.26s-15,6-13,20h6S27.13,14.26,37.13,6.26Z"/><polygon id="string" class="cls-1" points="41.13 125.26 43.2 57.26 44.37 57.26 45.13 125.26 41.13 125.26"/></g><g id="turtle"><path id="body" class="cls-1" d="M37.13,122.26s-18-1-33,20c0,0-5,1-4,4s8,8,6,11-7,9-4,12,15-6,15-6,18,12,41,1c0,0,2,0,2,4s-1,11,2,11,10-12,10-12,4-4,1-7c0,0-2-2-1-3s7-6,11-1,4,7,10,7,14-3,14-3,5-2,2-6a39.88,39.88,0,0,0-7-7s-2-3-7-2-10,3-8,1,2-3-1-3c-1,0-18-16-29-18S45.13,122.26,37.13,122.26Z"/><path id="highlight-2" data-name="highlight" class="cls-2" d="M5.13,145.26s26,36,76,0C81.13,145.26,34.13,188.26,5.13,145.26Z"/><circle id="eye" class="cls-2" cx="97.63" cy="152.76" r="4.5"/><circle id="eyeball" class="cls-1" cx="99.13" cy="152.26" r="1"/></g></svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

Since this method is expecting an HTML element, I suspect it is encountering object issues transforming a SVG object. I am trying to research this jQuery feature with SVG yet not finding a lot of details so far.

Hope this helps clarify it. You could also hide another SVG behind that helps animate the *pop* or not use SVG. Not sure what is better.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Interesting, I can see it happening in your version. Not the way I thought it would but it is getting the color at least.